# c++ CMake project structure for lib and executable

Tags: c++, cmake, build, clion, directory-structure

I have a question regarding how to structure a c++ project and build that using CMake (inside of CLion). I am very new to c++ (I started to learn the language only two weeks ago) and to CMake (I haven't ever configured a CMake file). I do however have a bunch of experience with other programming languages and their ecosystems like Java, JavaScript, Php, and .NET—perhaps analogies with those ecosystems could help?

We're building our own (small, 2d) game and game-engine for a school project. The game engine should be shippable on its own, the game should build on our own engine. The engine will have its own dependencies (built using SDL2, thats a requirement).

I imagine the engine will become a (static) library, while the actual game will compile to an executable that depends on the engine library.

For the purposes of simplifying project management we're looking to host both the engine and the game code in the same git repository.

Given that we might want to put a `math` module into our engine (probaby not the case, but for the purpose of this question) I imagine a folder structure like the following:

```
our-project/
├── README.md
├── engine
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── math.cpp
│   │   └── math.h
│   └── test
│       └── ...
└── game
    ├── src
    │   └── main.cpp
    └── test
        └── ...
```

The engine would then contain the following code:

```cpp
// in math.h
namespace engine::math {
    int add(int a, int b);
}

// in math.cpp
#include "math.h"

namespace engine::math {
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Let's say we wanted to make use of this engine code from our game, I imagne the following code:

```cpp
// in game/main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "engine/math.h"

using namespace engine;

int main() {
    std::cout << math::add(10, 1) << std::endl;
}
```

### Questions

1. How do I setup CMake so that I can both build the engine (static library) individually, and build the game (executable) that depends on that same engine?
2. How should I manage the engines header files? How do I make them accesible to the game code? Should I use a different structure for the header files?
3. Is this folder structure manageable? Should I consider a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You declare separate CMake targets, i.e., in `engine/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   add_library(engine
       math.cpp)
   ```

   while in `game/src/CMakeLists.txt`, you have

   ```
   add_executable(my-game
      main.cpp)

   target_link_libraries(my-game
       PRIVATE
       engine)
   ```

   When using e.g. `make`, you can build the targets individually by

   ```
   make engine # build only the engine, not the executable
   make my-game # build engine if necessary, then build executable
   ```

   Separate test targets make sense, too.
2. Include flags in CMake are propagated as follows.

   ```
   target_include_directories(engine
      INTERFACE
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
   ```

   The above setup propagates an include directory to all targets that link against engine. This is simple, but has a drawback: you can't distinguish between public headers and implementation details. As an alternative, you could have a directory `engine/src/public/engine` with all *public* headers that shall be used by the game:

   ```
   target_include_directories(engine
      INTERFACE
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public)

   target_include_directories(engine
      PRIVATE
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public/engine)
   ```

   This way, client code in `game` uses `#include "engine/math.h"`, while in `engine`, you can just go with `#include "math.h"`. I like such a setup, as it's easily visible what is the interface of a library and what is its implementation. But it's also somewhat a matter of taste.
3. Again opinionated. But I think this is a good directory structure. Stick to it.

Comment: Any reason why you put the `CMakeList.txt` file inside of the `src/` directory?

Comment: It's supposed to be the `CMakeLists.txt` that is responsible for that directory. You would have another one in `tests`, and one in the level above, e.g. `engine/CMakeLists.txt`. The latter does nothing but `add_subdirectory`. This hierarchical structure is common and doesn't yield any surprises.

Comment: Ah OK, that's clear, thanks!
I'll try this setup in a minute when I have some time. Let's see if I can get this to work.

Comment: Should both engine/ and game/ do their own `project()` calls? In their respective CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: No, only one `project()` at the very toplevel root directory.

Comment: "The above setup propagates an include directory to all targets that link against engine." 

Are you saying here that the `INTERFACE` keyword will cause any `other` library or executable target that calls `target_link_libraries(other engine)` to also use the same include directory? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yes exactly! Technically it's not the `INTERFACE` keyword that does that but rather `CMake`'s target-oriented mechanics that propagate usage requirements like include directories to targets that link against this libraries. So you could also have an `add_library` without `INTERFACE` (in this case you have to add sources, while `INTERFACE` allows header-only library targets), and any target (executable or another library) linking against it with `target_link_libraries` will automatically have the correct include directory setup.